# Changes to query string in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an action method that looks like this

```
public ActionResult MethodName(int num)
{
  viewmodel model = GetDetails(num)

  return View(model);
}
```

route config looks like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "MethodName",
 url: "{ControllerName}/{MethodName}",
 defaults: new {controller = "controllerName", action="MethodName"}
);
```

My issue is it gives the URL of 
www.mysite.com/controller/Method?message= 78545

I would like to have it as

> www.mysite.com/controller/Method/78545

Can anyone please help me with this? How can I achieve this? I have tried making changes to route config with no help. Do I need to make any URL rewriting or will there be a small fix for this in route config?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add, like, on top of your method, a route attribute, like `[Route(“Method/{num?}”)]`

Comment: Try above one and let us know!

Comment: Tried it and it does not make any change. The URL remains the same

Comment: It worked when I made changes to the num? to num. How can i make changes to the @url.action in the html?

Answer (score 1):

Change your route mapping to have an optional num parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MethodName",
    "{ControllerName}/{MethodName}/{num}",
    new { controller = "controllerName", action = "MethodName", num= UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your parameters to result in a querystring, you need to add optional parameters to your MapRoute. Then you load the parameter with the value you want to pass to the action result.

In the example below, you can access the method by calling it with "controller/action/op1" or "controller/action/op1/op2", you get the idea. (if op1 equals the value 1, the url will look like 'controller/action/1', same for the other parameters)

**[ Add Optional Parameters ]**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{op1}/{op2}/{op3}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", op1 = UrlParameter.Optional, op2 = UrlParameter.Optional, op3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```